# how to register custom converters for spring messaging, web sockets @DestinationVariable or jms @Header

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-jms, spring-websocket, spring-messaging

I'm integrating spring web sockets capability into an existing spring mvc application, everything works as expected, except for enabling custom Spring Conversion on my inbound messages via @DestinationVariable.

Now I already have custom converters fully working for the http side, ex @RequestParam or @PathVariable  but the same conversion on a websocket controller method throws a ConverterNotFoundException

Ex. I have a custom converter that converts String into Users

```
public class StringToUserConverter implements Converter<String,User>{
    @Autowired UserDAO userDAO;

    @Override
    public User convert(String id) {
        return  userDAO.getUser(Integer.parseInt(id));
    }
}
```

And this works exactly as expected in my http controllers, where I can pass in an id, and its automatically converted to the domain class

```
public String myControllerMethod(@RequestParam User user)
```

However the same does not work for my websocket controller for a parameter annotated with @DestinationVariable

```
@MessageMapping("/users/{user}")
@SendTo("/users/greetings")
public String send(@DestinationVariable User user) {
    return "hello"
}
```

I stepped through the code and I can see that the DestinationVariableMethodArgumentResolver  has the default conversion service which doesnt include my custom coverters

So how do I register custom converters, or a custom ConversionService so that it works for web sockets like it already does for http controllers

Answer (score 0):

So now I'm running into the same issue with @Header annotation for JmsListener methods.

Same idea, @Header User user, throws the ConverterNotFound exception.

```
@JmsListener(destination = "testTopic")
public void testJmsListener(Message m, @Header User user)..
```

Here I was trying to pass the user id on the message header, and have spring convert it, but to no avail, only basic default conversions are supported, like strings or numbers.

I have stepped through quite a bit of initialization code in Spring here, and I can see that a new DefaultConversionService gets instantiated in many places, without any consideration for external configuration.

It looks like these modules are not nearly as mature as Spring MVC or the developers took a shortcut. But based on my inspection there is no way to easily configure custom converters.

Answer (score 0):

Ok and here is the very hacky, not recommended, approach that did work. Its pretty convoluted and brittle, Im not going to use it, but just for illustration purposes here is what it took to register a custom converter for @Header jms mapping.

Here Im passing in a user_email on the jms message header, and wanted spring to automatically convert the id/email into the actual domain object User. I already had a working converter that does this well in mvc/http mode.

```
public class StringToUserConverter implements Converter<String,User>{

    @Autowired 
    UserDAO userDAO;

    public User convert(String email) {
        return userDAO.getByEmail(email);
    }
}
```

The above part is pretty standard and straight forward. Here comes the idiotically convoluted part. I stepped through the spring jms listener initialization code and found lowest spot where I could cut-in with my custom converter for jms @Header.

I created a service, that will @Autowire one of springs Jms beans, and then sets a custom conversion service on it using @PostConstruct. Even here some of the properties were private, so I had to use reflection to read them

```
@Service
public class JmsCustomeConverterSetter {

    @Autowired
    StringToUserConverter stringToUserConverter;

    @Autowired
    JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor jmsPostProcessor;

    @PostConstruct
    public void attachCustomConverters() throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        //create custom converter service that includes my custom converter
        GenericConversionService converterService = new  GenericConversionService();
        converterService.addConverter(stringToUserConverter); //add custom converter, could add multiple here
        DefaultConversionService.addDefaultConverters(converterService); //attach some default converters

        //reflection to read the private field so i can use it later
        Field field = jmsPostProcessor.getClass().getDeclaredField("beanFactory"); //NoSuchFieldException
        field.setAccessible(true);
        BeanFactory beanFactory = (BeanFactory) field.get(jmsPostProcessor); //IllegalAccessException

        DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory f = new DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory();
        f.setConversionService(converterService);
        f.setBeanFactory(beanFactory); //set bean factory read using reflection
        f.afterPropertiesSet();
        jmsPostProcessor.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(f);
    }
}
```

Creating the DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory was based on code I saw in org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.MessageHandlerMethodFactory.

I would definitely not recommend using this in production. It is fairly brittle and unnecessarily complex.

Spring...sometimes it's a breath of fresh air... and sometimes it's convoluted-clap-trap